# Using a local geoPath variable for multiple maps using the same path data, different projections in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use the new local() feature in d3 v4 to render several maps with different projections on the same page – my idea being to use different, locally-defined map projections depending on the class of the parent DOM element.

But I'm having trouble getting the locally-defined path function to return a proper SVG path string.

Here's my HTML – "fullwidth" classed elements are large, and "small" elements should display as small multiples with smaller-scaled projections:

```
<div id="nonenglish" class="map fullwidth" style="width: 100%"></div>

<div id="white" class="map fullwidth" style="width: 100%"></div>

<div id="origins_Europe" class="map small" ></div>
<div id="origins_Canada" class="map small" ></div>
<div id="origins_Africa" class="map small" ></div>
```

And the relevant Javascript is below (note: the maps render – albeit all at the same size – when I define the path variable globally, so I've ruled out any issues with the JSON data or the promises.):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {  

let mapWidth = d3.select('.fullwidth').node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
        mapHeight = (window.innerHeight > mapWidth) ?  (mapWidth * 1.1).toFixed(0)  : (mapWidth * 0.8).toFixed(0);

svg = d3.selectAll(".map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", function() { 
        return d3.select(this.parentNode).classed("small") ? mapWidth/3 : mapWidth;
    })
    .attr("height", function() { 
        return d3.select(this.parentNode).classed("small") ? mapHeight/2 : mapHeight;
    })
    .attr("class", function() { 
        return d3.select(this.parentNode).classed("small") ? "small_svg" : "fullwidth_svg";
    });

let files = ["censusData.json", "mainecounties_topo.json"];

Promise.all( files.map(url => d3.json(url) ) ).then(function(results) {

  var censusData = results[0];
  var pathData = results[1];

    var counties = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class','countymap')
        .each( (d,i) => { 

            let s = (i<2) ? mapWidth * 10 : mapWidth * 6;

            let p = d3.geoConicConformal()
                    .parallels([29.5, 45.5])
                    .rotate([70.58, 1.1])
                    .center([-.8,50])
                    .scale(s)
                    .translate([0, -s/40]);

            path.set( this, d3.geoPath(p) );

            console.log(path.get(this).projection().scale())
            // Everything looks OK here!

        });

    counties.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(pathData, pathData.objects.counties).features)
        .enter().append('path')
        .attr('class','counties')
        .attr('d',  d => { 
            let p = path.get(this); 
            console.log(p); 
            // It looks like a path function in the console...
            return p;
        } 
        .attr('fill',  '#ddd'  );

});
}
```

One last clue: when I go to inspect my `<path>` elements, this is what they all look like –

`<path class="counties" d="function e(t){return t&amp;&amp; (&quot;function&quot;==typeof o&amp;&amp;i.pointRadius(+o.apply(this,arguments)),_r(t,r(i))),i.result()}" fill="#ddd"></path>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs for #local.get()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local_get):

> Returns the value of this local on the specified node. If the node does not define this local, returns the value from the nearest ancestor that defines it. Returns undefined if no ancestor defines this local.

And as you're setting the value of your **local variable (d3.local())** as `path.set( this, d3.geoPath(p) )`, the *returned* value of `path.get(this)` would be a function which you need to call AND passing the `d`.

Changing the appending of path code to this:

```
.attr('d',  d => { 
   let p = path.get(this); 
   //console.log(p); 
   // It looks like a path function in the console...
   return p(d);
})
```

should get you the paths' `d` attribute correctly. Here's a reference example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e1192fe405703d8321a5187350910e08

Hope this helps. It'd be always better if you provide a fiddle/plunkr - a working snippet so that it'd be easier to edit the code and provide back a working URL.